# Getting UnsatisfiedLinkError when using renderscriptSupportModeEnabled with System.loadLibrary

Tags: android, renderscript, loadlibrary, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a project with some native library. When I enable `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled`, I am getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError` error at line of `System.loadLibrary()`. I am using SDK 22 and 21.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by renaming `armeabi` folder to `armeabi-v7a` !